# How to make a PHP page have two "column" regions?

Tags: php, html, mysql, multiple-columns

Basically I'm doing digital signage and I'm trying to get names to be pulled from a MySQL database to a PHP page. Right now its all centered in one column, but I want the results to be in two columns side by side. How can I do this?

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM donor WHERE DonationAmount = 5000 AND Category = '1' or DonationAmount = 5000 AND Category IS NULL ORDER BY LastName ASC";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

            // test if the DisplayName field is empty or not
            if(empty($row['DisplayName']))
            {
                // it's empty!
                    if(empty($row['FirstName'])){
                        echo $row['LastName']. "<br>";
                    }

                    else{
                        echo $row["LastName"]. ", " . $row["FirstName"]. "<br>";
                    }

            }else{
                // Do stuff with the field
                    echo $row["DisplayName"]. "<br>";
            }

    }
} else {

}
```

Basically I want this data to be spread across two columns instead of 1 single page.

Comment: Can you give and example of how the output should be?

Comment: This is what it currently looks like: http://imgur.com/bj17wjv -- I would like the amount heading to stay centered, but have the names in that category span across two columns

Comment: so you have do set some div and/or span Tags to style your out put. this is more a question on html/css and not on php...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use tables, and count the rows to determine if you need to start a new table row.

```
$i = 0;
$total_rows = $result->num_rows;
echo "<table><tr>";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

    // test if the DisplayName field is empty or not
    echo "<td>";
    if(empty($row['DisplayName']))
    {
        // it's empty!
        if(empty($row['FirstName'])){
            echo $row['LastName'];
        }

        else{
            echo $row["LastName"]. ", " . $row["FirstName"];
        }

    }else{
        // Do stuff with the field
        echo $row["DisplayName"]. "";
    }
    echo "</td>";
    $i++;
    if($i % 2 == 0 && $i != $total_rows) {
        echo "</tr><tr>";
    }

}
echo "</tr></table>";
```

Answer (score 1):

output the strings like this:

```
echo "<span style=\"width:50%;float:left;\">".$row['LastName']."</span>";
```

do not forget to remove `<br />` from each output

Comment: can I specify something like this in the head of the document or something so that it automatically does it for every output?

Comment: you need at least span around it. to have something to style

Comment: unfortunately I do not know what that means, I am a SQL guy, not PHP, so this is quite a struggle for me.

Comment: if you can't edit it in PHP, you can write some JS method to split the content by <br />s and wrap the values with spans

Comment: see my another answer

Answer (score 0):

if your content is in `<div id="myDiv">` use this JS function and call it after the content loads

```
function splitValues() {
  var output = "";
  var names = document.getElementById('myDiv').innerHTML.split("<br>");
  for(var i in names) {
    output += "<span style=\"width:50%;float:left;display:inline-block;text-align:center;\">"+names[i]+"</span>";
  }
  document.getElementById('myDiv').innerHTML = output;
}
```